# How to append multiple objects in array with jquery each() method

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, each

There is an array called `employeeDetails` and in that array there are 3 objects.  I want to append the 3 objects and their properties to my `table` using jQuery's `each()` method.

I am trying, but it's not working. I did it with a `for` loop and it was successfully created but when I used `each()` I am not able to view it. I want it done through the `each()` method. Please help me and correct me where I am wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var employeeDetails = [{
    srNo: 1,
    doj: '20 April 2011',
    dob: '11 June 1987',
    name: 'Aniket Paste',
    designation: 'Web Designer',
    salary: 30000,
    address: 'Borivali East'
  },{
    srNo: 2,
    doj: '10 April 2011',
    dob: '15 May 1987',
    name: 'Amey Sawant',
    designation: 'UI Developerr',
    salary: 50000,
    address: 'Borivali East'
  },{
    srNo: 3,
    doj: '21 June 2014',
    dob: '11 December 1989',
    name: 'Mahesh Parab',
    designation: 'FrontEnd Developer',
    salary: 45000,
    address: 'Dahisar East'
  }]

  $(".btn").click(function() {
    // for(i = 0; i < employeeDetails.length; i++){
    //   var data = "<tr><td>" + employeeDetails[i].srNo + 
    //     "</td><td>" + employeeDetails[i].doj + 
    //     "</td><td>" + employeeDetails[i].dob + 
    //     "</td><td>" + employeeDetails[i].name + 
    //     "</td><td>" + employeeDetails[i].designation + 
    //     "</td><td>" + employeeDetails[i].salary + 
    //     "</td><td>" + employeeDetails[i].address + 
    //     "</td></tr>";
    //   $('table').append(data);
    // }

    $('table').each(function() {
      $('table').append(employeeDetails);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button class="btn btn-default mb15 mt15">Add Data</button>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Sr.No.</th>
    <th>D.o.j</th>
    <th>D.o.b</th>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
    <th>Designation</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- 
  <tr>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>24.04.2012</td>
    <td>20.04.1988</td>
    <td>Aniket Paste</td>
    <td>Web Designer</td>
    <td>30000</td>
    <td>Borivali East</td>
  </tr>
  -->
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The `for` loop you had working originally is the correct way to do it. Using `each()` on the table is the wrong way of approaching the logic.

Comment: Rory McCrossan, thank you for your answer. But I want a way how to do it through each() method or is it impossible with each() ?

Comment: It's possible, but pretty redundant. While `$.each()` can be used to iterate arrays, the logic would be identical to the `for` loop you already have. All you would be doing is adding jQuery in where it's not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a string version of the table rows (using a forEach loop to iterate over the array) and then pass it into the html of the table (doing it this way allows iteration over the array without  the cost of appending each row to the DOM individually. Not a big issue for small tables - but a big table with multiple columns and rows could create a rendering issue if the DOM is modified on each iteration.

I would also suggest with doing away with the button and simply having the table build itself on document.ready() but that is up to you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      var employeeDetails =  [                    
                            {
                                srNo:1,
                                doj:'20 April 2011',
                                dob:'11 June 1987',
                                name:'Aniket Paste',
                                designation:'Web Designer',
                                salary:30000,
                                address:'Borivali East'
                            },
                            {
                                srNo:2,
                                doj:'10 April 2011',
                                dob:'15 May 1987',
                                name:'Amey Sawant',
                                designation:'UI Developerr',
                                salary:50000,
                                address:'Borivali East'
                            },
                            {
                                srNo:3,
                                doj:'21 June 2014',
                                dob:'11 December 1989',
                                name:'Mahesh Parab',
                                designation:'FrontEnd Developer',
                                salary:45000,
                                address:'Dahisar East'
                            }                    
                        ]


$(".btn").click(function(){
  var str = '';
                   
    employeeDetails.forEach(function(employee){               
  str+= '<tr>';
    str+= '<td>' + employee.srNo + '</td>';
    str+= '<td>' + employee.doj + '</td>';                       str+= '<td>' + employee.dob + '</td>';                   
    str+= '<td>' + employee.name + '</td>';
    str+= '<td>' + employee.designation + '</td>';               str+= '<td>' + employee.salary + '</td>';                 
    str+= '<td>' + employee.address + '</td>';  
  str+= '</tr>';  
 })
  $('#employeeTable').append(str);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <title>each</title>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
                <![endif]-->
                <style> 

                </style>
            </head>
            <body style="width:800px; margin: 0 auto;">

                <button class="btn btn-default mb15 mt15">Add Data</button>

                <table class="table table-bordered" id="employeeTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sr.No.</th>
                        <th>D.o.j</th>
                        <th>D.o.b</th>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                        <th>Designation</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
employeeDetails.forEach(function(item){
   $('<tr>', {
     html: '<td>'+item.srNo'</td>'+....other fields
   }).appendTo(table);
});
```

You may use construction like this, or for loop

Comment: nice - this is exactly what my solution does - only thing -  I build the string in the function and pass it into the table only at the completion of the forEach loop - that way it appends only once instead of the multiple times this way alters the DOM. Not a big issue for small tables - but a big table with multiple columns and rows could create a rendering issue if the DOM is modified on each iteration. Apart from that - great minds and all.... :)

Answer (score 0):

`.each()` is designed to iterate over the DOM elements, not the array. So your solution with `for` loop is definitely better.

What is even better is @Oleksiy's solution, because surprisingly `.forEach()` method uses less memory than classic `for` loop, so if you're optimisation freak use `.forEach()` but after all, it doesn't matter because your array size is small so you won't notice any speed difference.